# Update a many-to-many relationship with TypeORM, Nest JS

Tags: many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

I'm having trouble updating an entity that has many-to-many.

Below are the product entities and categories.

```
@Entity()
class Products {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public title: string;

  @Column()
  public content: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Category, (category) => category.products)
  @JoinTable()
  @Type(() => Category)
  categories: Category[];
}
```

```
@Entity()
class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Products, (products) => products.categories, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @Type(() => Products)
  products: Products[];
}
```

Update in my service.

```
  async updateProduct(id: number, product: UpdateProductDto) {
    await this.service.update(id, product);
    const updatedProduct = await this.service.findOne(id, {
      relations: ['categories'],
    });
    if (updatedProduct) {
      return updatedProduct;
    }
    throw new ProductNotFoundException(id);
  }
```

I do not understand what exactly the problem is, since the addition works, the data in the database is there, I send a change request with data similar to how to create it.

```
{
    "content": "test",
    "title": "test",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Error message

```
 [ExceptionsHandler] column "productsId" of relation "products" does not exist +23003ms
QueryFailedError: column "productsId" of relation "products" does not exist
    at new QueryFailedError (...\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:12:28)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\typeorm\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.js:248:31)
    at step (...\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.throw (...\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:124:57)
    at rejected (...\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:115:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```